# Dropdown list for Story points in Agile

Tags: tfs, agile

I am trying to add drop down list to story points; obviously which is not happening. i have some questions:

1. Is it like pre-defined, coz it dosent allow me to change the existing one?
2. I have created a new field as "MyStory Point" and have dropdown, which works perfectly fine, will this work same as the existing Story Point or do i need to make changes to some other files also.

My new field is:

```
<FIELD name="MyStory Points" refname="My.Points" type="String" reportable="dimension">
        <HELPTEXT>The size of work estimated for implementing this user story</HELPTEXT>
<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
         <LISTITEM value="1" /> 
        <LISTITEM value="2" /> 
        <LISTITEM value="3" /> 
        <LISTITEM value="5" />
        <LISTITEM value="8" />
        <LISTITEM value="13" />
        <LISTITEM value="21" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
      </FIELD>
```

then under `<control>` tag:

```
<Control FieldName="My.Points" Type="FieldControl" Label="MyStory Points:" LabelPosition="Left" />
```

Is this correct?? will this work for a story point??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that if you choose, but any out-of-the-box reports that reference the old field will break.  And if you have any customizations (e.g. custom reports, custom warehouse adapters, custom cubes, etc) they could potentially break also.

Possibly a better way would be to keep the original field but don't display it on the form (by changing the CONTROL as you have done).  Then ensure that whenever your new field changes value it is copied into the old field. This way the old field is still around so none of the reports or other pieces that depend on it will break.  Something like this:

```
<FIELD name="Story Points" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" type="Double" reportable="measure">
    <WHENCHANGED field="My.Points">
        <COPY>My.Points</COPY>
    </WHENCHANGED>
</FIELD>
```